# Measure integration problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume $A_j,j\geq 1,j\in\Bbb N$ are measurable sets. Let $m \in N$, and let $E_m$ be the set defined as follows : $x \in E_m \Longleftrightarrow x$ is a member of at least $m$ of the sets $A_k$.

I wanna know how to prove that

1. $E_m$ is measurable.
2. $m\lambda(E_m)\le\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\lambda(A_k)$.

It's hard to me. Help me T.T

Comment: For the first question, try to write $E$ as a countable union involving the $A_j$, using the fact that the subsets of $\Bbb N$ which have $m$ elements is countable.

Answer (score 3):

Call $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{A_n}$. Here are some hints:

- Show that $S$ is a measurable function (possibly as the pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable functions). Note that $E_m=[S\geqslant m]$, and deduce item 1.
- Compute the integral $I$ of $S$ in terms of the sequence $(\lambda(A_n))_n$. Show that [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) reads $m\lambda(E_m)\leqslant I$ in the present situation, and deduce item 2.